# I want my selenium web driver to use my chrome cookies and I also want to pass the driver instance created once to be used in another method

Tags: java, class, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I want the chrome driver instance created in main method to be used in the method handlecase

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, OpenXML4JException {
             
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\sample\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            static WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
            options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/sample/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

public static void handlecase(String type) {
        
        for (i=0; i<num; i++) { 
            driver.get(type);
}
}
```

Here we get the error as driver cannot be resolved.

I tried this workaround

```
public class criteria {
        static ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();     
        static WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, OpenXML4JException {
             
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\sample\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/sample/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

public static void handlecase(String type) {
        
        for (i=0; i<num; i++) { 
            driver.get(type);
}
}
```

It worked but the problem is that it creates a new session and i cant use my cookies here.

Comment: first problem was a scope issue, which you resolved.  To use an existing profile, you'd need to set the profile in your options.  You should create a new profile in Chrome for this purpose.  I don't think you can use the default profile.  (...and don't expect most session cookies to be available... they are removed when the browser exits, and re-created when a new session has begun.... sometimes that happens after a login using a "remember me" type cookie which is not limited to session)

Comment: Can you rephrase your question as to what exactly you are asking for? Seems like a long statement to me.

Comment: @NeuronB, I need to invoke chrome which uses my current session and i need to access the driver in all methods.

Answer (score 0):

You get "driver cannot be resolved" error because the "handlecase" method doesn't know what "driver" is. Read [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/amp/) to learn about variable scopes in Java.

The workaround you posted doesn't throw this because here the variable "driver" is a static variable belonging to the "criteria" class and can be accessed by all it's methods. As to why it is creating a new session, not enough information is available. Please post how you call the "handleclass" method if you are interested in an answer to this.